# Print result of subtraction involving floating point numbers to two decimals

Tags: php, string, floating-point, number-formatting

I have 3 strings as 3 variables: `$amount1`, `$amount2`, `$amount3`.

Both, `$amount2` and `$amount3` have values after decimal points like 12.34 or 12.00

Now I am performing following operation like

```
$amount1 = $amount1 - ($amount2 + $amount3);
```

I need to display value of `$amount`, with decimal points even if it is not needed.

example:

```
$amount1     =         $amount1      -     ($amount2 + $amount3)
  12                       20               (6.00 + 2.00)
```

In above example, I am getting 12, but I need to display as 12.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$amount1 = $amount1 - ($amount2 + $amount3);
echo number_format($amount1, 2, '.', '');
// Echos 12.00
```

Link to PHP Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

If you are dealing with monetary values, you can use [money_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) method too.

Comment: small note: according to the PHP docs, money_format() is undefined in Windows

Answer (score 0):

Or [`(s)printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
printf('%.2f', 20 - (6.00 + 2.00));
```